# Adding (cloning) and removing columns (input elements) into div as last element

Tags: jquery, html

**This is what I have:**

```
<div id="sizes-field-cover">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="size-sizes-1[]" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="size-sizes-1[]" value="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="size-sizes-2[]" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="size-sizes-2[]" value="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="size-sizes-3[]" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="size-sizes-3[]" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**This is what I want to end up with (add another input element into all divs) when I click a `<button>`:**

```
<div id="sizes-field-cover">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="size-sizes-1[]" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="size-sizes-1[]" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="size-sizes-1[]" value="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="size-sizes-2[]" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="size-sizes-2[]" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="size-sizes-2[]" value="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="size-sizes-3[]" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="size-sizes-3[]" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="size-sizes-3[]" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**TO ADD:**

```
<button id="add-sizes-column">(+) Add</button>
```

**TO REMOVE:**

```
<button id="remove-sizes-column">(-) Remove</button>
```

**THESE TWO DONT DO ANYTHING:**

```
$('#add-sizes-column').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $cloned = $('#sizes-field-cover div div:last').clone();
    $('#izes-field-cover div:last').after($cloned);
});

$('#remove-sizes-column').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $cloned = $('#sizes-field-cover div div:last').remove();
});
```

Comment: You mean `onclick`, not `click`, don't you?

Comment: Correct. "...when I click a <button>..."

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle of that?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/nc2C7/

Comment: Your selector to get a clone of the element is wrong, and you also have a typo in the selector when using `.after()`.

Comment: I've deleted my answer as I didn't get what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this solution. it append textbox in same row instead of new row as mentioned in your question.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/iamrmin/6UBK9/)**

```
$('#add-sizes-column').click(function(event) {
    debugger;
    event.preventDefault();

    $("#sizes-field-cover div").each(function(index, val){
        var oCloned = $(val).find("input:last").clone();
        $(val).append(oCloned);
    });
});

$('#remove-sizes-column').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $("#sizes-field-cover div").each(function(index, val){
        $(val).find("input:last").remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove a div word

Eg:

```
var $cloned = $('#sizes-field-cover div:last').remove();
```

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Zqy9/)

Comment: My comment written for @MalenciaUK's answer applies to you as well. Your is same

Comment: I agree, a lot of answers came while I was writing mine. (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo of a solution

http://jsfiddle.net/LaLtJ/

Basically I am utilizing your code but Instead breaking up and handling each div individually by looping though the divs.  I believe this is the result you want.

```
$('#add-sizes-column').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#sizes-field-cover div').each(function() {
        var $cloned = $('input:last', $(this)).clone();
        $('input:last', $(this)).after($cloned);
    });
});

$('#remove-sizes-column').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#sizes-field-cover div').each(function() {
        $('input:last', $(this)).remove();
    });
});
```